# How many (set theoretical) functions $f:\emptyset\to\emptyset$ and $f:\left\{1\right\}\to\left\{1\right\}$ exist? Re: zéro puissance Zéro.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the essay [Zéro puissance zéro. Zero to the Zero-th Power](https://www.scribd.com/document/14709220/Zero-puissance-zero-Zero-to-the-Zero-th-Power), the author makes the assertion that the number of functions $f:\emptyset\to\emptyset$ is 1.  How is this proposition justified?

I can give an argument that there are no function.  That is, a function is a set of unique ordered pairs such that every element of the pre-image appears exactly once as a first element in the set of pairs, and the second element of each pair is an element of the image set.  By this definition, $f:\emptyset\to\emptyset\iff \left\{\left<x,y\right>\right\}=\emptyset$, so $\text{card}\left(f\right)=0$.

If we admit the null mapping as a function, and also the identity mapping, we might argue that we have a degenerate case in which both are the same mapping, and therefore $\text{card}\left(f\right)=1$.  Or we might insist that these are still somehow distinct functions, and thus $\text{card}\left(f\right)=2$

So I ask: **How many (set theoretical) functions $f:\emptyset\to\emptyset$ and $f:\left\{1\right\}\to\left\{1\right\}$ exist, and how is this explained?**

Comment: I don't follow your question.  A function is merely a special case of a relation, and a relation on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$.  The empty-relation is a perfectly valid relation and the empty-relation happens to satisfy all of the properties required to be considered a function in the case that $A$ is empty.  That it happens to satisfy all of those conditions *vacuously* is of no concern.  As such, the empty-relation (*and as such the empty-function*) is a perfectly valid function to consider over the empty set.

Comment: Further, if you were somehow suggesting that the null-mapping and the identity mapping are distinct... how? Why?  For $A$ the empty set, the null-mapping and the identity-mapping are both the empty-relation and are equal as sets and so are not distinct at all.

Comment: What you have called the empty function, I have called the null function.  There is also the identity or universal function.  Shall we count those as distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the domain $X = \emptyset$, the only function is the null function $f = \emptyset$.  If a function is a set of ordered pairs with certain properties, then this $f$ is the empty set, containing no ordered pairs.  It is vacuously true that every element of the domain $X= \emptyset$ (there are no such elements) appears exactly once as a first element in the set $f = \emptyset$.  So there is one function from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$.

The identity function on $\emptyset$ is the same as the null function $f$: it is vacuously true that $f$ maps every element of $X$ (there aren't any) to itself.

On the domain $X = \{1\}$, you have the identity function as you know.  The null function $f = \emptyset$ is not a function on $X$, since there exists an element of $X$ (namely 1) that does not appear as the first element of any ordered pair in $f$ (since $f$ contains no ordered pairs).  So there is one function from $\{1\}$ to $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument is wrong.

You are confusing "Every element of..." and "There exists an element of...".

It is true that there is exactly one function $\varnothing \to\varnothing$, and there is exactly one function $\{1\}\to\{1\}$. The first is $\varnothing$, and the second is $\{(1,1)\}$.

Comment: Ok.  I see an error in my counting.  I counted the number of elements in $\emptyset \to \emptyset \iff \emptyset$.  But the set of functions is $\left\{\emptyset\right\}.$

Answer (score 2):

It's true that every element of the empty set has a unique pre-image because there are none. It's an instance of being [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: Is proof by vacuous truth also vacuous?.  In particular, if once presents a proof by vacuous truth, and then a contrary result, does that not undermine the vacuous truth?

Comment: @StevenHatton I'd argue it this way. What can you say about Nothing? Well, you can't really say Nothing is Something but you can say Nothing is a green-eyed lion and the moon. Nothing will travel faster than the speed of light. Nothing made us meet face-to-face to duel today, etc, etc. You can say pretty much anything you want about Nothing and it's true.

Comment: I will meander off into metaphysics and claim there are two kinds of nothing: non-substantive nothing, and substantive nothing.  What is contained in a completely empty box?  That which is contained in the box is substantive nothing.  My point regarding proof based on vacuous truth is that the conclusion  is only as sound as the premises.  While it seems necessary in order to make progress in mathematics, assuming vacuous truth could, as Kant put it, lead to "milking the he-goat" if we are not careful.

Comment: @StevenHatton Vacously true statements are a logical standard more than metaphysics. It's a natural consequence of our agreement that logical implication will always be true when the premise is false. You can always justify it as mere symbol shunting in a Boolean algebra if your skepticism remains unsated.

Comment: I didn't mean that my entire reply pertained to metaphysics.  The first part was intended as an aside comment.  My statement about proof founded on vacuous truth was cautionary.  Vacuous truths are assumed to not lead to contradictions.  But it is possible to make different assumptions of vacuous truth abut the same entity $0^0$, in this case.  If we lose track of such assumptions,  we may end up encountering apparent contradictions which are man-made.  This is my pragmatic justification for studying foundational mathematics.